# about __new__() to initialize the object in python

Tags: python

I have read the source code of datetime.date() in which we can just find **new**() but **init**.  But we can pass parameters to the class without **init**_(). Could someone tell me how the code processes.

Comment: Interesting. Could you please include a link to the code in the question?

Comment: I would suggest to first read this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__, then this https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/#instance-class-and-static-methods-an-overview and https://www.concentricsky.com/articles/detail/pythons-hidden-new.